# How to explode items in sub-components using LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I need to explode composed items in sub-items and sub-items in raw materials using LibreOffice Calc. The project is for a furniture factory who wished to explode the order in tier or layers of production.

For example product A001 is made with B01, B02 and C02, B01 is made with 1xC01 anc 2xC02, finally B02 is made with 3xC01, 1xC02 and 4xC03 the customer wants to explode A001 in its components obtaining a list of how many B elements are required and how many total C elements are required to assemble B elements to produce the item (A elements are the items) of course he can input in the sheet that he need 2 x A001.

What is the best practice to make this possible with LibreOffice Calc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize the list in a top-down breakdown like this.

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

The formula for cell B14 is `=SUMPRODUCT(A$3:A$11=A14,B$3:B$11)*B$13`.  Then drag it down to B18.

The indenture level shows that part A001 is the top (level 1), and is composed of parts B01, B02 and C02 (level 2).  Part B01 is then composed of C01 and C02 (level 3), and likewise for part B02.

To create the unique list at the bottom, copy A4 to A11 and paste somewhere out of the way such as row 20.  Then [use a Standard Filter to remove duplicates](https://superuser.com/a/627755/541756).

Documentation for SUMPRODUCT is at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMPRODUCT_function.

For anything but very simple products, you'll probably need a database of some kind to maintain the information, and perhaps a third party software package.

At a large company where I once worked, we used an Oracle database to store information for each component, with a front end written in Java.  Reports could then be generated in spreadsheets similar to what is shown above.

Comment: it looks cool, how are you using the indenture level columns? Also they need the details on how many B01, B02 not the total of how many B and C components, this way can send precise orders from the storage to provide necessary elements.

Comment: Edited the question to address these concerns.

Comment: An alternative way to show indenture level is by indenting the ID number with spaces.